# I want to transfer the tokens from one contract to another address

Tags: smart-contracts, transactions, taquito, transfer, tokens

When I transfer the token from the contract address: `KT1LkNWZgVYh3zdaRkBb9aNgLEFCjVJwEKu2`, it works well. However, when I switch back to the address `KT1P8RdJ5MfHMK5phKJ5JsfNfask5v2b2NQS`, an issue occurs. Below is my code:

```
const { TezosToolkit } = require ('@taquito/taquito');
const { InMemorySigner } = require ('@taquito/signer');


const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://ghostnet.ecadinfra.com/');
Tezos.setProvider({
  signer: new InMemorySigner('edskRpi3j2hwiRqRvjoETUe99L14Kz796pLS3N6rq6K3sLC9Xq2BY27KhTFtAUtkgEwacZWvsFaJ6Cnju2EWNYSEJkhDSwjGzf'),
});
var from = "tz1MSint56iUqoogrKsvEMEykpbKv2Yhmzss"
var to  = "tz1S2aWw5Jhz7RBcAKvJYfAG82Mv9LhEUobc"
var amount = 99
async function tranfer(){

const contract = await Tezos.contract.at('KT1P8RdJ5MfHMK5phKJ5JsfNfask5v2b2NQS');
await contract.methods.transfer([{ 
  from_: from, 
  txs: [{ to_: to, token_id: 0, amount: amount }] 
}]).send();

 }
tranfer()
```

The error I encounter is:

```
AddressValidationError: [from] Address is not valid: [{"from_":"tz1MSint56iUqoogrKsvEMEykpbKv2Yhmzss","txs":[{"to_":"tz1S2aWw5Jhz7RBcAKvJYfAG82Mv9LhEUobc","token_id":0,"amount":99}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because both contracts have different parameter schema for the `transfer` entrypoint.

Goto [KT1LkNWZgVYh3zdaRkBb9aNgLEFCjVJwEKu2 TzKt](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1LkNWZgVYh3zdaRkBb9aNgLEFCjVJwEKu2/entrypoints), the arguments should be in the format:

```
"schema:list:object": [
    {
        "from_:address": "address",
        "txs:list:object": [
            {
                "to_:address": "address",
                "token_id:nat": "nat",
                "amount:nat": "nat"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Goto [KT1P8RdJ5MfHMK5phKJ5JsfNfask5v2b2NQS TzKt](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1P8RdJ5MfHMK5phKJ5JsfNfask5v2b2NQS/entrypoints), the arguments should be in the format:

```
"schema:object": {
    "from:address": "address",
    "to:address": "address",
    "value:nat": "nat"
}
```

So, for the other contract you should call it like this:

```
await contract.methods.transfer(from, to, amount).send();
```

Note that the order of the argument should be same as in the schema, that is `from, to, amount`.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you change is the contract address, the second contract's `transfer` entrypoint has a different set of parameter names. The [first one expects](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1LkNWZgVYh3zdaRkBb9aNgLEFCjVJwEKu2/entrypoints) `from_`, while [the second one expects](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1P8RdJ5MfHMK5phKJ5JsfNfask5v2b2NQS/entrypoints) `from`. Are you adjusting the parameter names properly?

Comment: That’s right, I only changed the contract address, the sender and recipient addresses remain the same, and the sender still has the new token balance of the contract.

Comment: Please let me know if updating the parameter names fixes the problem